# Unable to manage random popup in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I want to check constantly during automation that if popup came then close it otherwise continue with ongoing test cases.

I have read many answers available on internet but it does not help about how to check constantly for popup.

I can build one function to check it but then to call that function after each line of code would be not good practice so looking for some short and valid solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep checking every time, without repeating the code in every method, I would `implement my own WebDriver`

Doing so, you can `override` every WebDriver method and perform checking and handling the pop up at the very base level.

Example:

```
public class Selenium implements WebDriver {
private static HashMap<Thread, WebDriver> webdriverPool = new HashMap<Thread, WebDriver>();
private WebDriver driver = null;

private Selenium(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public static Selenium get() {
    WebDriver currentDriver = webdriverPool.get(Thread.currentThread());
    if (currentDriver != null) return new Selenium(currentDriver);
    else {
        //initialize WebDriver like this
        //add switches etc. Return an instance of our Custom class wrapping the WebDriver
        return new Selenium(new FirefoxDriver());
    }
}

@Override
public void close() {
    driver.close();
}

@Override
public WebElement findElement(By arg0) {
    handlePopUp();
    return driver.findElement(arg0);
}

@Override
public List<WebElement> findElements(By arg0) {
    handlePopUp();
    return driver.findElements(arg0);
}

@Override
public void get(String arg0) {
    driver.get(arg0);
    handlePopUp();
}

@Override
public String getCurrentUrl() {
    return driver.getCurrentUrl();
}

@Override
public String getPageSource() {
    return driver.getPageSource();
}

@Override
public String getTitle() {
    return driver.getTitle();
}

@Override
public String getWindowHandle() {
    return driver.getWindowHandle();
}

@Override
public Set<String> getWindowHandles() {
    return driver.getWindowHandles();
}

@Override
public Options manage() {
    return driver.manage();
}

@Override
public Navigation navigate() {
    return driver.navigate();
}

@Override
public void quit() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Override
public TargetLocator switchTo() {
    return driver.switchTo();
}

public void click(WebElement element) {
    handlePopUp();
    element.click();
}

public void click(By by) {
    handlePopUp();
    this.findElement(by).click();
}

public void sendKeys(WebElement element, String keys) {
    handlePopUp();
    element.sendKeys(keys);
}

public void sendKeys(By by, String keys) {
    handlePopUp();
    this.findElement(by).sendKeys(keys);
}

private void handlePopUp() {
    //your custom method
}
```

There are few things to remember. If you want to also override `click()` and `sendKeys()` methods, you have to implement them somewhere. Since these methods are implemented in `WebElement` interface, you would have to create interfaces somehow, overriding the ones created by selenium. That's possible but too costly I think.

I added `click()` and `sendKeys()` to `Selenium` class.

Instead of invoking `element.click();` you would have to use `selenium.click(element);` in order to handle the pop up.

The method `get()` handles creating the WebDriver.

Example of How to Use:

```
Selenium selenium = Selenium.get();
WebElement element = selenium.findElement(By.id("id"));
selenium.click(element);
```