# How to create callback for element appearing Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is an element on page that appears every 2-5 min. I want to click this element as fast as possible when it appears. I think I should use sth like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10000)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath"))).click();
```

And repeat it in infinite loop. But I need to wait this element asynchronously (in current thread I use this WebDriver for other actions), and I want to know how can I correctly do this. I read that WebDriver is not thread-safe, so it's incorrect to create new thread with infinit loop.

I consider it would be ideal to create some kind of callback for appearing of needed element, is it possible?

Comment: Some time ago I answered a question where a user wanted to click randomly appearing pop-up. Maybe it will guide you to the solution? [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699632/unable-to-manage-random-popup-in-selenium/48705031#48705031)